# Why is Intellij showing a cross (x) over the class icon for one of my Java classes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The icon that IntelliJ (v11.1) usually shows next to Java classes is a blue circle with a C. But for one of my classes this icon has a small "x" in the top left corner. This particular class is in a package with another class, which has just the usual C in a blue circle.

In case it matters, I'm using a Mac.

The class in question is **AlertsHandler**.

[image]

Comment: Or the full name of the class? Isn't this class deprecated?

Comment: jetbrains should provide documents  for this

Comment: IntelliJ icon documentation can be found at: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/symbols.html

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This icon shows that the **class is excluded from the compilation**, it can be changed in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Compiler` | `Excludes`.

Comment: @lucasmonteiro001 It happened because you pressed Exclude from Compile in Messages Make.

Comment: what is it "Messages Make" ?

Comment: @Ivan he was referring to the Messages tool window, Build (previously called Make) tab from where the file having errors can be excluded from the compilation. [See the screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/XMowi0O.png).

Comment: The same applies to the folders also.