# IntelliJ compilation issue, java cannot find symbol yet provides its location?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am developing an application in IntelliJ which has a class `HackTrickBoard` in a well defined namespace `AbstractGames.ConcreteGames.mnkGame.HackTrick`. In the same namespace I have created a new class `HackTrickGUI` with one method `Main`, in this method I simply instantiate a new `HackTrickBoard` class.

```
package AbstractGames.ConcreteGames.mnkGame.HackTrick;

// Marked as unused in IntelliJ
import AbstractGames.ConcreteGames.mnkGame.HackTrick.HackTrickBoard;

public class HackTrickGUI
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        //HackTrickBoard board = new HackTrickBoard();
        AbstractGames.ConcreteGames.mnkGame.HackTrick.HackTrickBoard board = new AbstractGames.ConcreteGames.mnkGame.HackTrick.HackTrickBoard();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this code I am given an error

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class HackTrickBoard
  location: AbstractGames.ConcreteGames.mnkGame.HackTrick
```

It seems that java cannot find the `HackTrickBoard` class yet knows where it is? IntelliJ had no issue finding it from the autocomplete menu and does not highlight its syntax as an error.

Is something wrong with `Main`?

In IntelliJ for the Run/Debug configurations I did not see an option for a command line application so I am starting this as a "Application", maybe this is the issue?

Comment: How does `HackTrickBoard` class look like? Post its contents and the screenshot of the project view with this file.

Comment: It is literally an empty class named `HackTrickBoard`.

Comment: Does it have the proper package statement, maybe it's excluded from compilation?

Comment: Yes the package is listed at the top of the file `package AbstractGames.ConcreteGames.mnkGame.HackTrick;`. Hmm, how can I check if its excluded from compilation. I actually think that might the issue..

Comment: The class icon will have a small cross (`x`) on it, that is why I asked a screenshot of the project view, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11055250/104891).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class could be excluded from compilation, it's indicated by a small `x` on the class icon in the project view.

Excludes can be removed here:

[image: excludes]