# Java IntelliJ Exception in Thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I've been getting this error pretty much on any new installation of IntelliJ on multiple computers.

The code I'm running is a simple hello world system out class.

```
public class hello {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("HELLO WORLD");
}
```

}

That's it.

Everytime I run this or anything else I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
```

I've tried:

- Revalidating my cache files
- recompiling the project
- setting the environmental variables to find the jdk and jre installations
- setting the correct source folders
- reinstalling jdk on windows and installing on ubuntu
- at one stage I had managed to get it running when i used a default java class template on something, it had a import or package statement, but I can't remember what it was, however after adding the import/package statement things had worked.

UPDATE: the package that appears to get it working is "package com.company;", why does this work? what does it do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks Guys.

Comment: Why did you add `android` tag to the question? Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891). Does it help?

Comment: Did you try running your Java Class from command line?