# IntelliJ cannot found my main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I do not know why it cannot found main class. In fact, I use terminal to run this, it works.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8hob.png)

[image]

Comment: You're trying to run a class called `Test` but your class name is `HelloWorld`...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is more precisely:

> Error: Could not find or load main class **Test**

Emphasis mine.
In the top-right corner,
notice the dropdown labeled "Test",
with a small red cross on it.
That's the currently active *run configuration*.
It's a previous configuration that you used that's no longer valid.

An easy way to run this program is using keyboard shortcuts:

1. Place the cursor inside the `main` method
2. Press Control Shift F10 at the same time

This will create a new run configuration, to execute the class you are currently in.
After this is done, observe the label on the dropdown in the top-right corner change to "HelloWorld", the name of your class.