# Just installed IntelliJ, and it cannot find or load my main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried making a fresh install on IntelliJ CE IDEA because I had the same issue earlier. Before you count this post as a duplicate, I'd like to say that it's not. I've tried to use other solutions provided by other people in other posts, and none of them seem to work to my need. I'd like for this post to stay open until a permanent solution is found.

I'm creating a new Java Project using IntelliJ IDE, and the creation runs fine. However, when I run the Main method which does not contain any code at all, it throws this error:

```
objc[3671]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x100d104c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x100dd84e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Error: Could not find or load main class net.kingdomnetwork.core.core.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried multiple solutions like reinstalling the IntelliJ IDE, rechecking the main class path, and all sorts of other answers that were seen in other posts. I am able to compile a JAR file and run it successfully using my local Terminal, and other IDEs seem to work to my liking. However, every time I attempt to run my code, I end up with the same error every time. Is it possible that I need to reinstall the Java Development Kit [JDK], or is this strictly something JetBrains has to fix on their own time?

Thanks so much for your help, and again,  please don't mark this as a duplicate. If it was a duplicate, I wouldn't have posted it.

Comment: Your JDK installment seems the cause of problem, have a clear install of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that method did not work. I've done this twice now, and the same error occurs. I've created a new project, and the same error is thrown. Reinstalling the JDK did not fix the issue.

Comment: Did you install same version of jdk? If so, try different version.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891.