# Button "Ok" not being selected when choosing main class intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, run-configuration

I am trying to run a program in the run configuration I am creating, the button "OK" is not being selected when I choose the main class...

Here's a image of the problem :

[image]

Anyone can help ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891.

Answer (score 6):

In the project window, right click on your "src" folder, and then choose "Mark Directory as -> Sources root."

Then come back to run configuration and choose your class. It should appear in the first tab ('Search by Name') itself.