# Firebase with java admin SDK gives error when project exported as JAR

Tags: java, firebase, intellij-idea, firebase-admin

i am trying to create a java application using firebase admin sdk
this code is tested

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount =
new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)).build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

and it works **perfectly fine**
 the problem appears when the jar file is exported, when using this command `java -jar fileName.jar` an exception appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions$Builder
    at Launcher.initFirebase(Launcher.java:22)
    at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

after searching for the problem, the issue was suggested to be *exported jar doesn't include the library*. so i forced the exported jar to contain the library like this[image]

still the error is the same. any suggestions?

Comment: Jar inside jar will not work, it has to be extracted, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder still exactly the same, i have included the library. check the update

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).