# Intellij "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

I installed intellij and it keeps giving me error:

```
Could not find or load main class sample.Main
```

I checked many answers for similar questions and non of them worked. The program I'm trying to run:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("hello");
    }
}
```

[image]

Run Configuration
[image]

Settings
[image]

[image]

[image]

"out" folder is not getting created. Full run command used by intellij after expanding "..."

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe"
>   "-javaagent:E:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2018.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=51072:E:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar" com.company.Main

Comment: Did the com.company file and import appear there on its own? I don't think that's supposed to be there when running IntelliJ on a fresh install.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding?

Comment: Check the output directory has write permissions, check build.log for errors (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085), see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891 answer. What's the output path you are masking out on your screenshots?

Comment: @HowardP I created sample command line application that comes with intellij.

Comment: @shmosel I tried rebuilding and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I checked that answer before and all suggested options didn't fix my issue. Intellij has write access to output folder. The masked output folder is just in same location as project itself. There is no need for masking as you can see the path in intellij title.

Comment: @AnthonyJ. share the logs (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: @CrazyCoder please download them from we.tl/t-8rouVyKTnZ

Comment: `Module 'untitled104' is skipped: e:\Projects\JavaFX\CompleteDeveloper\untitled1\untitled104.iml doesn't exist ` The project seems to be corrupted and the module file is not found by the compiler. Try creating the new project from scratch. If it doesn't help, zip and share the entire project directory ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: That was actually new project. Anyway, I again created simple command line project and still same issue. I checked log and it gives exactly same problem "untitled104.iml" doesn't exist. The "iml" file of the new project is named "Stackoverflow.iml" not "untitled104.iml"!

Comment: I had a similar problem; I solved it by reinstalling IntelliJ - can't figure out why my former installation was awry...

Comment: my default IML file had     <exclude-output /> inside the <component/>

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to CrazyCoder, I could find the root of the problem. Intellij is using wrong iml file in "modules.xml" file. Change the iml value in modules.xml manually and rebuilding the project fixed the problem.
[image]

Of course this is just a work around. I think I have problem my intellij as it always using wrong iml file for all new projects.

Comment: Thanks man you saved my life, exactly the same thing happened with me

Answer (score 1):

I just faced error in my IntelliJ also, for me all the setting looks good even though it was not working. I removed `main.iml` file and right click and run program. Again it's created new `main.iml` and works fine.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to find an answer to the same issue, eventually, I hope that was the reason, I deleted the content of the "out" directory and re-run. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

[June 2020 Answer] Works with all Intellij versions.

Select `File` menu `Project settings`. (or `CMD` + `;` in mac)

Click Artifacts -> New Jar (+) -> Empty

( Now you will get option to create Manifest file)
[image]

Then Manually add the libraries and META-INF path which should be inside resources directory.

Make sure to include `Module Output Folder` also inside jar.

[image]
I created a video to help this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPGSas_f0ts

Answer (score 0):

> Simplest solution: Restart your device.

Have you reinstalled IntelliJ? I think there's an error in IntelliJ configuration files.

It creates incorrect IML configurations. You can get rid of it by creating a Gradle project.

I'm sure you won't face this error in a Gradle project. If you do, please don't have a look at the first solution. Jump to the second one.

> ***First Solution***
>
> 1. Try to uninstall with an uninstallation tool like IobitUninstaller
>    or any other you like.
> 2. Restart your device.
> 3. Open the JetBrains
>    directory which was created in the ProgramFiles folder.
> 4. If there's
>    a "JetBrains" folder, then delete it.
>
> ---
>
> *(Remember step 4 will delete all of your IntelliJ products. So if you have any other IntelliJ product, you can only delete the terrible
> product.)*
>
> ---
>
> 5. Then open up the ProgramData folder in your System drive, then look for another JetBrains folder.
> 6. Delete it too.
>
> *(Remember step 6 will delete all of your IntelliJ products. So if you have any other IntelliJ product, you can only delete the terrible
> product.)*
>
> 7. Then access the AppData folder which is hidden under your windows
>    user account. (Ex: "C:/Users/user/AppData/").
> 8. Then go to the "Local" folder and look for the JetBrains folder.
> 9. Delete if
>    there's one.
> 10. Then go back to the AppData folder again and go to "LocalLow" and do the same.
> 11. Then back once, go to the Roaming folder, and do the same again.
>
> So you've completely uninstalled the JetBrains software.
>
> 12. Then access JetBrain's official website, [www.jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com), and download the latest IntelliJ Idea version.
> 13. Then install it.
> 14. Restart your device.
> 15. Try to create a HelloWorld project and try to run it.

> Note: Try to search for remove Registry files too. But I think this
> isn't needed.

If this way didn't work for you. then we can have a look at the second
solution.

> ***Second Solution.***
>
> 1. Remove IntelliJ again as we discussed. (Have a look at solution 1).
> 2. Install a beta build and try again.

If it doesn't work either, then the third way.

> ***Third Solution.***
>
> 1. Uninstall your JDK.  2) Reinstall it. GrallVM is recommended.

> ***Last Solution.***
>
> !) If no way of these worked for you. Then you may like to reset your
> device!