# Intellij Cannot build jar from project modules

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I've multiple modules in a project. Later I added multiple spring-boot modules (not dependent on each other) just another projects/services.

The root project builds a jar with no issues.  But the other modules in that project doesn't build at all.

error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.app.server.namingserver.NamingServerApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.server.namingserver.NamingServerApplication
```

Ive tried all possible solution from this post ([How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly))

***My IntelliJ version***

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-182.3911.36, built on August 7, 2018

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

macOS 10.13.6

Any other solution?

Comment: this has nothing to do with building a jar, rather with a dependency missing from your repository/classpath -> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.server.namingserver.NamingServerApplication

Comment: adding manifest file/folder in resources worked for me. in past, i had same issue but now i don't remember how i solved it

Comment: NamingServerApplication is a separate module and it has no dependencies. I also have a manifest at this path /src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: It turns out  $JAVA_HOME is empty. Also, i cannot run the from cmd line by java NamingServerApplication.class   I added export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) but it still has the same error. Anyone got a similar type?

Comment: Seems you have no understanding of classpaths and dependency trees in Java.

Comment: @vyeluri5 see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891.

Comment: I was able to make this work by generating Jar (copy to the output dir and link via manifest). I later tried copying the same class-path to single generated Jar with no luck!