# Scala - IntelliJ IDEA Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, linux, scala, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am currently using **IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4** which I am trying to integrate with **Scala** but to no avail.

I have installed the **Scala** and **SBT** plugins and used the following steps in creating my project:

- File > Create New Project
- Selected **Java** from the left
- Selected **Scala** from the right > Next
- Entered the name of the project > FINISH

From there, the project is created. Following other guides, I then:

- Right click on the **src** directory
- New > File
- Enter **main/scala/Main.scala**
- And enter the following code in there:

**Code:**

```
package main.scala

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
```

But after right clicking in the editor and selecting **Run Main**, I get the following message:

**Error: Could not find or load main class**

Has anyone experienced this or can provide any solution?

**Note**

I have also tried creating a Scala application with sbt but the syncing process for the sbt dump never ends or gives an error and when I run the project, I get the same error.

Comment: Seems like it would make more sense to select a Scala project in step 1, rather than a Java project with Scala support...?

Comment: @jwismar Sorry, just updated my question. I tried that (Scala with sbt) but the syncing process remains ongoing (never ends or fails) and when I run the code I get the same error.

Comment: Sorry to tell you, I followed the steps above except created a Scala project with SBT. I was not able to reproduce the problem. It printed "Hello World" and terminated normally.

Comment: Follow this tutorial: http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-1-getting-familiar-intellij-ide/where-is-main-method-launch-scala-application/ You name eerything main, which I think is not very clever to do.

Comment: @DilyanoSenders I recently followed that and I have tried different names for the object file but same result.

Comment: @jwismar With no modifications or changes?

Comment: That's correct. Only the change in project type. Otherwise cut-and-pasted your code snippet. I also double-checked that I'm using the same version of IntelliJ as you are.

Comment: @jwismar How long does the syncing (sbt dump) take?

Comment: no noticeable delay. seconds at most.

Comment: @jwismar What sbt version are you using?

Comment: Could you go to the "build" menu and choose for "Rebuild Project"

Comment: Looks like I'm using sbt 1.1.6. And I'm on a Mac, if that's relevant.

Comment: @OmariCelestine check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891.

Answer (score 1):

For Intellj IDEA, probably you will need to double check your module settings, and see if your `scala` folder is marked as `sources` root.

Check this URL for more details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html

Answer (score 1):

When I experienced this issue after recreating your situation almost exactly step-by-step, what fixed the problem was putting the scala file, in your case `Main.scala`, in another package, named anything you want it to be, inside `main/scala`. Ultimately, the scala file's path would be something like

`main/scala/<package-name>/Main.scala`

Then, after fixing the package name in the scala file and running the scala file through IntelliJ, everything worked as it was supposed to.