# ClassNotFoundException With Only Class?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

I have been attempting to build a java project for about two hours, and I have found multiple resources telling me this and that about what to do to resolve my `ClassNotFoundException` exception. None of them are working for me. At first I thought it was an error with how I was exporting my JAR in Eclipse. However, when I tried to run my code in IntelliJ IDEA Community it still would not work.

My code is over 1000 lines, and thus won't work here. What confuses me though is that I only have one file, "KeyStatistics.java". A `ClassNotFoundException` exception makes sense if I were trying to access a file by the wrong name, but I only have one file here.

I am using JDK 12, and I built the project in IntelliJ idea after not customizing any of the build settings at all. I would love help because right now my only option looks like dissecting each part of my code and that could take several more hours.

**Note:** when I was using Eclipse, the project could run perfectly fine (because Eclipse doesn't actually build the project when it runs it).

**Edit:** here is the entire error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class KeyStatistics
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: KeyStatistics

Comment: No information here. Too abstract for anyone to suggest anything. Add more information about the file and it's content and what exactly are you doing? What is the exception

Comment: The exception message will tell you *which* class is not found.  What does it say?  The accompanying stack trace will tell you what code was trying to access the named class.  What does it say?

Comment: What class is it throwing ClassNotFoundException for?

Comment: Additionally, no, you certainly should not post your whole 1000-line class, but that does not mean you cannot construct and present a [mcve], which is what we want anyway.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added the error to my question.

Comment: @DavidConrad The error appears to be coming from the same class. Take a look at the error I put in the question.

Comment: The error cannot be coming from your class, because the VM is not successfully loading your class.  This is because either it does not exist -- maybe you assigned it to a package, whereas you are trying to refer to it by an unqualified name; maybe the class name is misspelled in the file; maybe ... -- or perhaps it is not in the classpath.  There are too many possibilities, so again, present an MCVE.

Comment: How are you running this? You said you're building a jar. What's the command line?

Comment: @DavidConrad First, I'm not running it because it has the error. Second, I'm not sure what the command line is because IntelliJ and Eclipse were both doing it for me.

Comment: I'm completely confused. You said you were exporting a jar from Eclipse. I assumed you were then trying to run that jar, or run *with* that jar on your classpath. You're going to have to provide a clearer description of what you're actually doing for anyone to help you.

Comment: A [`ClassNotFoundException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) is thrown at run time, not at compile time. Therefore, _"I'm not running it because it has the error."_ does not make sense to me. What are the steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Ptray plase see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here:

1. You are using the single file Java from source, a feature that was added in Java 11.
2. You are running in the IDE and the compiler output path is mis-configured.

### Option 1 - Using the Java 11+ single file feature

In that case you need to specify the file name with the ".java" extension, e.g. from the directory that contains `KeyStatistics.java` you would run (even if the file specifies a package name):

```
java KeyStatistics.java
```

Be sure that you are running Java 11 or newer, in case you have multiple versions installed, e.g.

```
$JAVA_11_HOME/bin/java KeyStatistics.java
```

The working directory should be the directory that contains that file, even if it specifies a package.  For example, if KeyStatistics.java is in a package org.stats, and normally you would refer to it as `org.stats.KeyStatistics`, when running a single file from the source you will run it using the directory delimiter, e.g. `/`, and not the package delimiter `.`.

So from the root directory of that project you would use

```
$JAVA_11_HOME/bin/java org/stats/KeyStatistics.java
```

### Option 2 - Mis-configured IDE path:

Open the project structure dialog in IntelliJ-IDEA and ensure that the `Project compiler output` is configured properly.

Then go into the Modules and select the module that contains your code.  Make sure that `Compiler output` is either set to `inherit project path` or points to the right directory.