# How to include .class files in intellij jar build

Tags: class, intellij-idea

I have set up my artificat so it appropriately builds a jar file and includes the source, manifest file etc. However, it does not include the class file. Is there a way to include that as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class files are included by default into the jar artifact you create for the module.

It's controlled by the `compile output` entry in the artifact:

[image: compile output]

You may not have the classes included if the source roots are misconfigured or the files are excluded from compilation, or for some other reasons described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891) for the sample project link that you can download and verify the correct project/artifact configuration so that you can compare it with yours and find what's wrong.