# IntelliJ - Why can't I run some classes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just started learning java and for some reason, I can't run any class other than the main one. When I right click on another class, there should be a "run" green arrow button, but for me there isn't. What's even more weird is that when I use my laptop, it works perfectly fine. What's the problem?[screenshot of what doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcPW5.png)

Comment: It looks like JDK is not configured properly for the project. Check out https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html . Try to delete and configure the JDK again. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891 .

Comment: Has your class been compiled?

Comment: Write click from the editor and press run