# New scala project in Intellij - Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I just created a simple helloworld scala project in Intellij. My main class is simply printing Hello World -

```
package xx.yy.zz

object HelloWorld{

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    System.out.print("Hello World!")
  }

}
```

My project structure

```
scala-test
|_src
  |_main
    |_scala
      |_xx
        |_yy
          |_zz
            |_HelloWorld
```

In the project structure settings, I have "scala" as my source folder. I am able to select my main class correctly in the application run configuration I created. So far so good. After this, when I try to run my run configuration, I get the dreaded error -

```
Error: Could not find or load main class xx.yy.zz.HelloWorld
```

At this point, I have tried all the things I could find on google like invalidating cache, reloading project, switching source folder to be "src" instead of "scala" and many others that I have lost track of by now. Please help!!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891. Does it help? If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder. I had already reviewed this post. It sure helped me in initial stages. My problem turned out to be in the gradle file. I had listed my repo and dependencies under "subprojects" instead of "allprojects". Fixing this fixed my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't investigate the reasons for this issue but as a workaround, you can compile the project via sbt/shell sbt before running via Intellij.