# Intellij debugger screens blank

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

[image: Intellij debug screens are blank]

All of my IntelliJ debug screens are blank. I have tried a number of classes now including the tutorial one from IntelliJ but nonmatter what I do with the break point I never get an output in the debug window when running in debug mode.

I was asked to upload a video which is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8tnhuh16afz0scz/Intelij_debug_201012.mp4?dl=0

This is the same result with any class I look to debug

Below is the config as Matt requested

[image]

Comment: Can you share the video of what you are doing? It looks like debugging session is not active and the code is not stopped on the breakpoint. Once any breakpoint is hit, the UI will be populated with more details.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the drop-down box to the left of the "Debug" button that you're pressing, this is where the debug profiles/configurations are setup.

Comment: Try moving the project outside of Dropbox. Breakpoint is not hit and the debugging session finishes for some reason. Normally a checkmark would appear on the breakpoint. Also note that IDE displays the class as not found in your run configurations. It may be related to the broken project configuration possibly caused by Dropbox sync. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891.

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to the prompt from @crazycoder I had to use the Project Structure dialogue to remove all of the Content Roots and then to start again adding just the root folder (scr in my case). With that fixed the class is found and the debug runs.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I am have a this issue. When I see this error, I am try to start debug in other opened project in IDEA, and in all of they DEBUG don't worked.
My solution was very simple - restart my computer. It is help me.