# I'm getting an error saying could not find or load main class com.company.main - beginner to java and intellij looking for guidance

Tags: java, intellij-idea

so I'm absolutely new to Java. I downloaded JDK and and IntelliJ IDEA to start programming. I'm getting a weird error and am not able to work around this problem. I've attached an image of what exactly it shows me in IntelliJ

[IntelliJ Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP9W0.png)

I've tried googling but couldn't find a work around. Please could you help me?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891. Also note that IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.x doesn't fully support Java 16. If you need to use Java 16, please try https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons why this is failing. But in your case i strongly feel that you have not set your java class path variable. If you set the java classpath variable it should work.

Comment: Most of the reasons are already described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891. If nothing helps, user should contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new.