# Error when running jar : Could not find or load main class , Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Community Edition) , I upgraded it to the latest verion and since then I'm facing this error even when I downgraded it.
Any project I make runs fine inside the IDE but the jar file built using `build artifacts` never runs from cmd, shows this error
`Error: Could not find or load main class E:\HelloWorld\out\artifacts\HelloWorld_jar\HelloWorld.jar Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`
I tried the solutions at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/10998081) but nothing seems to work.

here is the jar file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/raw/1p2inr054qsjhcs/HelloWorld.jar
([scanned by VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/69d7b0e68715e71b87ad475044143a5048eaa28a092e123fe17b41109d3afb07) , or run the jar online in this Colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14XSePfUoc_9J56Vy3mDPL-97-OgCstjs?usp=sharing) )

and the project folder zipped : https://www.dropbox.com/s/raw/wzxz0z48x1shkyk/HelloWorld.zip (scan [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/c6b365e91a13bd5d68718249f71be0a171081eb8d0de638efb4ee51c851fa9b1?nocache=1))

[image]

Comment: How do you run the jar from the command line? It works fine for me if I launch it as follows: `java -jar HelloWorld.jar` Try to delete `build/out/.gradle` directories and rebuild your project from scratch using `Build | Build Artifacts... | Build`

Comment: OMG the time i wasted yesterday, thanks alot, '-jar' was the cause , should I delete the question ? or close it