# IntelliJ Idea Class is x-marked and everyone using it is failed to compile

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I just noticed that in my IntelliJ idea project some class is marked with "x" and it causes compile errors in idea yet sbt/maven compiles it fine. Here is what I mean

[image]

You see the "x"-mark on the second from the bottom class. What does it mean?

Comment: You can get some light here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055016/why-is-intellij-showing-a-cross-x-over-the-class-icon-for-one-of-my-java-class

Comment: @Elvermg Thanks much!